# Android - Recursive file search gives NullPointerException

Tags: android

I have the following function to recursively search for a string within files, however it keeps giving a `NullPointerException`. When it is first called it seems to work, but once it recursively calls itself, `files` is *null*.

```
public void recursiveSearch(File searchDirectory, String searchString){
    File[] files = searchDirectory.listFiles(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isDirectory()){
                recursiveSearch(files[i], searchString);
            }
            if (files[i].getName().contains(searchString)){
                searchResultFiles.add(files[i]);
            }
        }
}
```

Here is an example of how it is called:

```
recursiveSearch("/", "abc");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried it this morning, and some system directories do give a null to isDirectory(). Also an empty directory would give back a `null`, so just simply put a null pointer check and it will work fine

```
public void recursiveSearch(File searchDirectory, String searchString){
  if(searchDirectory!=null)
    File[] files = searchDirectory.listFiles(); 
    if(files!=null)
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isDirectory()){
                recursiveSearch(files[i], searchString);
            }
            if (files[i].getName().contains(searchString)){
                searchResultFiles.add(files[i]);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I see is that File.listFiles() returns null if the File is not a directory. I would suggest testing searchDirectory.isDirectory() instead of assuming it is.